# 'NoneType' is not iterable error with for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, nonetype

I've gone through many questions about the 'NoneType' error, but I can't figure out why this basic for loop gives me a:

TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable.

```
lst = [1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
new = list()
for i in lst:
    if i not in new:
        new = new.append(i)
print(new)
```

Comment: You issue is the line `new = new.append(i)` Instead, just do `new.append(i)` Better still, `new=set(lst)` if you are just trying to get unique values.

Comment: append does not return anything. so it returns None implicitly.